# Using other library in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, email, google-chrome-extension, smtp

I'm trying to create email notifications for my chrome extension and am using https://smtpjs.com/ to send an email from me to the user. It would be really straightforward for websites, but chrome does not allow adding other scripts. I tried making it its own file and including it in the manifest, some content security things to add to the manifest I found from stack overflow, but it all resulted in errors. Now, I have the script for smtp right in my popup js, but the email still does not send. Help!

Code for email part:

```
 var Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t) { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText; null != t && t(e) }, a.send(n) }, ajax: function (e, n) { var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e); t.onload = function () { var e = t.responseText; null != n && n(e) }, t.send() }, createCORSRequest: function (e, n) { var t = new XMLHttpRequest; return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t } };

Email.send({
    SecureToken : "token",

  To : "emailimsendingto@gmail.com",
  From : "myemail@gmail.com",
  Subject : "testttt",
  Body : "testtttttttt"
}).then(
  console.log("sent")
);
```

I am getting the "sent" message in console, but no email. one problem could be an email I got about gmail blocking an outside site thing, the smtp. I thought I resolved it by saying it was me, but idk. I'm not sure how to check

Comment: warning! your token would not be very secure this way

Comment: it sounds like this service locks the secure token to a certain domain - not to an extension

Comment: it is the only safer way than putting my actual password and username. and for your second comment can you explain some more? not quite sure I understand

Comment: JS libraries can be used by extensions, Chrome doesn't disallow it. You may have made an accidental mistake though in your code/html. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @Huddy i believe that service locks it to a certain origin and chrome extensions do not have an origin.

Comment: so do you thinkits a lost cause?

Comment: @wOxxOm do you think you know what the mistake is? i looked through and couldn't find anything out of the ordinary

Comment: I can't help further until I see more of your code. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question please.

Comment: the thing is there is nothing else in the code that has anything to do with it. i don't have a button to send it or anything, I just run it straight from the js. it was just for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, realized I needed a smtp server. set it up with elastic email. messages go to spam folders, but it works :D